# innerHTML giving NaN output

Tags: javascript, parsing, socket.io, innerhtml, nan

I have got this function that gets data from a websocket into and an array. From that array, I have gone ahead to spilt the values into different variables. Unfortunately I keep getting `NaN values when I pass into`innerHTML`. I am parsing the array wrongly? Please see my code below

```
socket.on('data_added', function(mess) {

  var x = [];
  x.push(mess);

  var humidity = [];
  var temperature = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    temperature.push(x[i].temperature);

    humidity.push(x[i].humidity);
  }

  humidity = document.querySelector('#weather > p:nth-child( 2 )');

  temperature = document.querySelector('#weather > p:nth-child( 1 )');

  temperature.innerHTML = 'Temperature: ' + parseFloat(temperature[0]) + '&deg;C';

  // Populate humidity
  humidity.innerHTML = 'Humidity: ' + parseFloat(humidity[0]) + '%';

  console.log(temperature);
  console.log(humidity);
});
```

I will appreciate your effort.

**HTML file**

```
<div id="weather">
    <p>Temperature:  &deg;</p>
    <p>Humidity:  %</p>
</div>
```

Comment: just check the value in temperature[0] i guess your error lies there

Comment: check or console.log(humidity[0])

Comment: @Sameer My array consist of only one value. Something like this `[19]`. How do I reference that?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal `console.log(humidity[0]);` gives me `20`.

Comment: @Ekom parsefloat will give you error is your array is empty and you are refrencing it correctly

Comment: @Sameer my array isn't empty. `console.log(humidity[0]);` gives me `20`.

Comment: and console.log(temperature[0]) ??

Comment: Show us the HTMl too

Comment: @Sameer `console.log(temperature[0]);` give me `19`.

Comment: @Manu I have added HTML file as well.

Comment: You're using the same variable `temperature` for the DOM element and the array. Once you assign `temperature = document.querySelector( '#weather > p:nth-child( 1 )' );` you can't use `temperature[0]` any more.

Comment: @Barmar You're right sir. Thanks so much. Fixed the issue.